# Ближайшее большее число

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$string = 10;
$array = [5, 20, 40, 66];
```

Каким способом можно найти в массиве ближайшее большее число? В данном случае должно быть число 20

Comment: дак вы начните перебирать элементы массива и сравнивать с искомым числом. как только станет больше/меньше, то завершите цикл

Comment: Массив отсортирован?

Comment: @teran спасибо, думал может для такой цели есть в php какая-нибудь функция по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$string = 10;
$array = [5, 20, 40, 66];

sort($array);
foreach ($array as $k => $v){
    if ($v > $string) {
       echo $v;
       exit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: `exit();` -> `break;`

Comment: Либо оберните в функцию, вот так: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97bbbacbffe6957a4c910712f544a34a141d8c8c

Comment: @Дмитрий ну не совсем это я ожидал. Надеялся, что в php предусмотрена стандартная функция для такой цели. Но раз нет - тогда ваш ответ тот самый. Правда, на сколько я понял `$k =>` лишнее, ведь массив без ключей

Comment: @Anenirycone, все правильно поняли, как уже говорил замените `exit();` на `break;` и уберите `$k =>`

Comment: @Anenirycone, измените условие с `($v > $string)` на `($v >= $string)`